# How to add source code to Spotlight in El Capitan 10.11.1?

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, spotlight

Developers have been using this Spotlight trick for quite some time to search their source code.

Add the file types you want to Spotlight RichText.mdimporter
info.plist /System/Library/Spotlight/RichText.mdimporter

*info.plist*

`<string>public.swift-source</string>
<string>public.objective-c-source</string>`

*Terminal*

`mdimport -r /System/Library/Spotlight/RichText.mdimporter
sudo mdutil -E`

But access is now restricted in **El Capitan**. Saving the info.plist is not possible.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Well, if you're a developer and you're comfortable with it, `csrutil enable --without filesystem` from recovery partition to disable filesystem protections of SIP?

Comment: I believe so. Actually `csrutil enable` without options should do, I believe. In any case, I'm not encouraging you to turn SIP off, so do it at your own discretion and do prepare for potential damage.

Comment: I don't know man, I would just grep.

Comment: `grep -r` searches recursively, and with `--include` you can further restrict search scope. So, if you organize all your source code under a certain directory, say `~/Projects`, then searching with `grep` shouldn't be hard.

Comment: As I said, `--include`. Adding a few more options that are generally useful when searching multiple files: `grep -rIHn --color --include '*.swift' 'break;' /xcode/Projects` (might as well save as an alias if you need to search often enough).

Comment: Funny. EasyFind by Devon Technologies works perfect...and it's free. I actually used to use this years ago for daily stuff but totally forgot about it. I have it set to only search .swift and .m file contents. Pretty bad that Spotlight can't even do this. lol  I did find something strange. It works with swift files but it doesn't work with playgrounds which is very unfortunate. http://www.devontechnologies.com/download/products.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot to Recovery HD and then disable SIP in terminal.app

```
csrutil disable
```

If you want to enable all protections except a few, you can poke holes in the protection to allow debugging, dtrace, modifying filesystem restricted files, etc..

```
csrutil enable -without fs
```

See [this nice answer by Rich Trouton](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209530/5472) as well as [his blog for details on SIP](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/). I can't find official Apple documentation about these options - perhaps WWDC 2016 will have new documentation on how developers can relax the default security to modify things and run custom kext, etc...

In short - once you disable or enable without the fs restrictions, you can then edit the files needed to change the spotlight indexing rules for RichText as before.

Comment: Hello. SIP was already mentioned in the above discussion. Looking for a more "native" solution. Thank you though.

Comment: This is the only native solution on 10.11. Sorry there isn't a better answer. It's the same for people wanting to use `dtrace` - you can't without relaxing SIP. Thanks for the thanks @tymac